# How to access https protocol from JS to spring boot using @requestMapping?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, ssl

Do you have any Ideas to access https url guys?
I really want to complete it. 
When I try to connect to Server like this, server send 403 error.
I created .cert and .keystore too.
Thank you for sharing your idea.

My Server Code(Controlling)

```
@Log4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/v0.1/login")
public class LoginSessionAPI {

    @Autowired
    UserService service;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String verify(@RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("pw") String pw) {

        String auth = service.excute(id, pw);

        return auth;
    }
}
```

Client Site(JavaScript)

```
function getService(userId, userPw, ipPort){

    var protocol = "https://"
    var HOST = protocol + ipPort + "/v0.1/login";
    console.log("HOST : "+HOST);
    var loginAuth;
    var loginJson = new Object();
    loginJson.id = userId;
    loginJson.pw = userPw;

    var loginRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();


    loginRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        // process the server response
        console.log("status : "+loginRequest.status);
        if (loginRequest.status == 200) {
            console.log("object : "+loginRequest.responseText);
            if(loginRequest.responseText === ""){

            }else{
                var responseLoginJson = eval("("+loginRequest.responseText+")");
                loginAuth = responseLoginJson.loginAuth;
            }

        } else {
            console.log("failed");
        }
    };
    loginRequest.open("POST", HOST, false);
    loginRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    console.log(loginJson);
    loginRequest.send(JSON.stringify(loginJson));
}



And then,
I call getService(id, pw, ipPort) function.
```

I created SSL Certification.
application.properties

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
server.ssl.key-password=123456
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
server.ssl.trust-store=cacerts.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=123456
server.ssl.protocol=TLS
server.ssl.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_25\u200C\u200B6_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
```

Comment: attach logs from browser

Comment: {"timestamp":1478303640819,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?","path":"/action/register"}"

Comment: I attached this header, but has still problem.
 
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
loginRequest.setRequestHeader(header, token);

Comment: Spring boot's version is v1.3.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

in SecurityConfig class
added

```
http.csrf().disable();
```

Comment: I guess this not a solution just workaround making your app less secure